# помогите переписать функцию под jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Доброе утро! В общем имеется функция:

```
function refresh_links(id_link,direction)
{
var http_request = $.ajax({

});
}



function refresh_links(id_link,direction)
{
var http_request = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {}
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            try
            {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                try
                {
                    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {}
            }
        }


    if (!http_request)
    {
        alert('Не вышло  Невозможно создать экземпляр класса XMLHTTP ');
        return false;
    }
        http_request.onreadystatechange = function()
            {replace_html(http_request,id_link,direction);};
        http_request.open('POST', 'link_list.php', true);
        http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request_string="direction="+direction+"&id="+document.getElementById("super_id").value+"&id_link="+id_link;
        http_request.send(request_string);
}
```

Мне нужно переписать это дело под jquery ajax. Я начал разбираться в этой теме и что-то заблудился немного. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это будет выглядеть в виде jquery ajax. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/